# Angular patchstate infinite loop

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngxs

I have an infinite loop when I use patchState to add a property in my state.
I want to add an array property in my state by updating it.
Here is the code:

state.ts:

```
@Action(UpdateUser)
updateUser({ getState, setState, patchState }:StateContext<DriveStateModel>, { payload }: UpdateUser) {
patchState({ item: {...getState().item, ...{users: payload.users}} });
```

component:

```
this.store.dispatch(new UpdateUser({users: myUsers}));
```

My store is well updated but the update action is triggered infinitely...
Does someone have an idea ?
Thx !

Comment: You may need to provide more code. From what I can tell what's happening is you're somehow calling updateUser inside your updateUser. This could be happening inside the method you provided or whatever is calling it. Try setting a break point inside this method and see what is calling it and then determine why that's happening.

Comment: is this action dispatched in some `select` callback?

Comment: The dispatch method is called inside an API success callback

Comment: why don't you want to show the full code? The example `this.store.dispatch(new UpdateUser(...))` seems meaningless and doesn't tell anything about infinite loop

Comment: Are you by any chance calling the dispatch in an Angular hook like ngOnChanges? (and yes we need more code, this can't be answered like this)